# How to set bindings for DB::raw?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In Laravel 5.7, I'm having an Eloquent query like this:

```
return User::findOrFail($userId)
    ->dogs()
    ->setBindings(['', '', '', '', $userId])
    ->get([
        'name',
        DB::raw('coalesce(birth_year, ?) <> ? as birth_year')
        DB::raw('coalesce(breed, ?) <> ? as breed')
    ]);
```

It's a little simplified example, but what I need in general, is passing the bindings to `DB::raw()`.

My example works, but I don't like the fact that I need to manually overwrite `$userId` that is supposed to come naturally from `user-dogs` relation. Also, I don't like it that all bindings are together.

Is there a better way to use `DB::raw` like in my example? I know there is a `selectRaw`, but I don't want to select all the columns raw.

Comment: Can you post your `dogs` relationship function to understand the database relationship between `user` and `dogs`

Comment: This relationship doesn't have anything to do with my question, but if you need it, it's many to many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selectRaw` adds a raw select expression. It does not select all the columns raw. It also has a second param for bindings, so you can use this:

```
return User::findOrFail($userId)
    ->dogs()
    ->select('name')
    ->selectRaw('coalesce(birth_year, ?) <> ? as birth_year', ['', ''])
    ->selectRaw('coalesce(breed, ?) <> ? as breed', ['', $userId])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it exactly like that before you posted. Good to know we agree :)